# IntelliJ IDEA: перекомпиляция и запуск Maven-базированного Java FX приложения в одно действие

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, maven

В обучающем видео по созданию Java FX в IntellIJ IDEA с помощью Maven, в pom.xml был только следующий код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example_artefact_id</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.App</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Когда я запустил `maven install` и даже появилось сообщение `BUILD SUCCESS`, то первый же вопрос, который у меня возник: "И что теперь?". Никакого запуска приложения не было. Потом я узнал, что надо создавать JAR-файл, для чего добавил следующий плагин:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>jp.co.yd.App</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Теперь вроде как всё работает, но получается, что для просмотра результата редактирования кода, нужно каждый раз выполнять два действия:

1. Maven Install
2. Открывать Jar-файл

Не могу поверить, если IntelliJ IDEA не позволяет всё это сделать разом, в одно сочетание клавиш `Shift+F10` или `Ctrl+F5`. Но как этого добиться?

Comment: Заходим в класс с методом `main` и нажимаем на стрелку рядом с этим методом или комбинацией клавиш. В IDEA всегда java проекты запускались стрелкой вверху после первоначального "ручного" запуска

Comment: @Bleser, Поверить не могу... Всё работает. Я правильно понял, что maven можно больше не трогать, пока не будут добавлены новые пакеты?